# Does jruby 1.6.3 in 1.9.2 compatibility mode works with rails 2.3.11? Meaning did somebody tried that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

We are using jruby 1.6.x and we would like to switch to 1.9 mode because of UTF8 support. However, we don't want to upgrade rails from 2.3.8/2.3.11 to rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to upgrade a Rails 2.3 application first to ruby 1.9.3. There were all kind of utf8-related problems. Some of them you can fix easily, by putting a utf8 header in the file, but some of the problems occur only in special conditions, for example when an error message is constructed from different parts somewhere deep in the rails stack, an one part was ascii, the other utf8. 
When I investigated the problems I found other have also different kind of utf8 problems.
So it easier to go first to rails 3.0 and then to ruby 1.9